# iOS: GUI Automation Testing and Continuous Integration

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, ui-automation

I have been writing iOS logic tests using OCUnit and OCMock and it's been working great. I want to start adding two things, GUI automation and continuos integration. I have been evaluating [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF), [JenKins](http://jenkins-ci.org) for my requirements. Can someone please direct me to correct root as this is the first time I am attempting GUI testing and continuos integration server for iOS. Which are the libraries look for automation GUI testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything better combination than KIF, WaxSim, and Jenkin! KIF is based on objective-c and you have complete control over it to add your customisations. Rest of all test frameworks is Javascript based which I am not big fan of!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Instruments - Automating UI Testing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)

Comment: Hi Wain, Thank you for this. it seems you cannot automate tests using Apple UIAutomation. We have to automate the testing and integrate to CI server so I don't think this will be an option for us to try out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FoneMonkey](https://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey-ios/fonemonkey-quick-tutorial) to UI iOS Automation and for CI process we use [TeamCity](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/03/23/building-xcode-projects-with-teamcity/). TC has a buit-in "XCode project" step to compile your project and anything else you can easy perform with command line steps.

Comment: Is there any way to run FoneMonkey from command line so that it can be a part of the continuous integration process?

Comment: Yes: http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey-ios/fonemonkey-user-guide/running-fonemonkey-ocunit/creating-test-runner-target

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part. I'm trying to look for pricing but couldn't find anything. Is the service free? I'd think not since there  seems to be a paid staff at Gorilla Logic.